# Is polarizing power related to solubility, melting point of a compound?

Tags: ionic-compounds, covalent-compounds

It is stated in [this websites](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Physical_Properties_of_Matter/Atomic_and_Molecular_Properties/Polarizability) that

"It is found that the greater the possibility of polarization, the lower is the melting point and heat of sublimation and the greater is the solubility in non-polar solvent"

Is it true for all circumstances? As the only application of polarizing power that I've known is to define the ionic or covalent character of a bond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the general rule about rules in chemistry that all rules have their exceptions. Except those they do not, as this rules applies on itself too.

Most of the rules are partly relying on rough models, partly being empirical. As they frequently do not consider minor effects, or are not even aware of them, there usually have exceptions.

Raising of covalent character can lead to molecular structures with low melting/boiling points like hydrogen halogenides, or long range structures and high melting points like silicon carbide.